# using curl on iOS, I am unable to link with multiple architectures, CurlchkszEQ macro failing

Tags: ios, xcode, curl

I have built numerous versions of curl using the wonderful "build_curl" script i found on GitHub. I have also rebuild curl using other techniques.

But I always end up with the same issue.

I have an iOS project which links against curl. I can build and debug on the simulator (clearly using i386). I can build and debug with a device as long as I choose to only build the current architecture and the device is plugged in when I build.

However, if I choose to try to build Release OR if I choose to build Debug for 'iOS Device' with no device plugged in. I always end up with the following error:

```
curlrules.h:143:6: '__curl_rule_01__' declared as an array with a negative size
```

This is caused by this:

```
#define CurlchkszEQ(t, s) sizeof(t) == s ? 1 : -1
typedef char
  __curl_rule_01__
    [CurlchkszEQ(long, CURL_SIZEOF_LONG)];
```

This #define exists in curlbuild.h

```
#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 4
```

Which should be correct, because I am building for a 32 bit architecture, however, Xcode has decided that `sizeof(long) != 4`, and so the Macro generates an error.

I have chosen to only build for armv7 and armv7s, and still I get this error.

I do not understand why this will not build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have chosen to only build for armv7 and armv7s, and still i get this error.

Have you looked at the Xcode build logs to confirm that only `-arch armv7` and `-arch armv7s` are used for compilation?

Your problem is certainly related to the fact that you use a single set of headers (e.g generated for a 32-bit build of the library) even though you try to build a fat executable that combines armv7/v7s and arm64 architectures.

I think you should refer to [Nick Zitzmann libcurl pre-built](http://home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html). As you can see the `curlbuild.h` header that ships with it includes ad-hoc macros to distinguish between ILP32 and LP64:

```
/* The size of `long', as computed by sizeof. */
#ifdef __LP64__
#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 8
#else
#define CURL_SIZEOF_LONG 4
#endif
```

*Note that the instructions on Nick's page do not include any precision about how this header has been generated - I would say it has been modified specifically to be cross-platform compliant.*

**UPDATE**

The above link is down (one can find a snapshot on the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/libcurl-ios.html) - the latest pre-built was made for libcurl 7.40.0 from 2015-01-08). I made a copy (verbatim) of `build-libcurl-ios.sh` and `curlbuild.h` (the single, convenient header made for the `iOScURL` application) [here](https://gist.github.com/deltheil/7fe3da9c7074fffa81cf).

After the `armv7` build the `build-libcurl-ios.sh` makes a copy of the generated 32-bit header:

```
cp include/curl/curlbuild.h ~/Desktop/curlbuild32.h
```

Same thing after the `arm64` build:

```
cp include/curl/curlbuild.h ~/Desktop/curlbuild64.h
```

The final `curlbuild.h` is no more than a convenient version that includes both 32-bit and 64-bit specifics thanks to `#ifdef __LP64__ /* ... */ #else /* ... */ #endif` sections. In particular there is more than only `CURL_SIZEOF_LONG` differences, e.g.:

```
#define CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_OFF_T int64_t /* 64-bit */
#define CURL_TYPEOF_CURL_OFF_T long    /* 32-bit */
```

Comment: With the above modification to the curlbuild.h header file, using Xcode 5.1, I can now build on iOS for all architectures. It does not explain why the previous version of Xcode was building for arm64 when I specifically excluded that from my settings, but since all architectures build and work now, I can move on...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to go through each of the differences between the 32-bit and 64-bit headers, so instead did this:

1. Made 32 and 64-bit builds of libcurl including headers, using the script found here: http://feedback.datalogics.com/knowledgebase/articles/821196-building-openssl-and-curl-for-ios-64-bit-platform
2. Put the headers into `include-32` and `include-64` directories.
3. Set header search-paths to include a directory above the directories created in step 2.
4. Created a header file called `my_curl.h` like so:

   ```
   #ifdef __LP64__
   #include <include-64/curl/curl.h>
   #else
   #include <include-32/curl/curl.h>
   #endif
   ```

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it saved me the time (and risk of mistakes) of doing it by hand.

Comment: Hey @arrtchiu I wanted to try your approach but the link u posted is broken. Do u know where i can find that script u used?

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. I eventually stopped using this approach in favour of a more integrated solution called hunter ( https://github.com/ruslo/hunter ) which took care of it.